# Set constant size of JScrollPane

Tags: java, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jtabbedpane, border-layout

I have a JTabbedPane with a Border Layout.

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to add the components:

```
add(columnNames, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(useCtrl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
setVisible(true);
```

**Question**:
Notice the excess whitespace to the right inside the JScrollPane. I don't want that there. I would like for the JScrollPane not to change size at all when changing the size of the JFrame. I have tried setSize() and setPreferredSize(), but the size of the JScrollPane always changes. I've tried using GridLayout, but I get the same result.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Take a look at [A visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  As has already been stated, `BorderLayout` will give over all the available space to the center component by default...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the `JScrollPane` in a `JPanel` with another layout. (e.g. `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout`). And add the `JPanel` to the center.

Answer (score 3):

The size of a graphics object is controlled by the layout manager.  The `BorderLayout` will always expand the `CENTER` object to take up all available space.  `GridLayout` expands all it's children proportionally.  If you try a GridBagLayout and set the `weightx` to 0, that will prevent expansion horizontally.

There are a lot of layout managers available, browse the API for more choices and experiment until you find the resizing behavior you want.  Each has a fairly good explanation of how it works in the javadoc.